# jQuery appears to sort elements randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of elements in the UI:

```
  $('.stuff').sort(function(a,b) {
    a = $(a).attr('data-date');
    b = $(b).attr('data-date');
    console.log(a + " > " + b);
    console.log(a > b);
    return a >= b;
  }).appendTo('#stuff_container');
```

The html looks something like

```
 <div class='stuff' data-date='1278395142'>...</div>
 <div class='stuff' data-date='1378395142'>...</div>
```

If I put logging in there, I can see that it's doing the comparisons correctly, returning true when the comparison is true. However in the UI when I run the sort, the elements appear randomly. If I execute this code repeatedly, it keeps randomizing the order. I can verify this in the debug console by seeing that the data-attrs are all not in order.

I can't find any reference on the goog as to what might be happening here. I will dive deeper into jQuery tomorrow, but thought I'd throw this out there. jQuery 1.4.2 (yeah..) Thanks!

Comment: Just be aware they'll be sorted lexigraphically, not numerically. Not the issue if it's randomizing them, but still.

Comment: As Dave said, you're comparing strings, not numbers. You cant prepend a `+` to cast them to integers.

Comment: The output of your console and the DOM you're running it on would be helpful... maybe put it up on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

The callback passed to [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is supposed to return a `Number`. Try:

```
return Number(a) - Number(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sort function is returning (after casting to numbers) `0` or `1`. The value `0` corresponds to "the values are equal" in `sort`.

Essentially, this means that if it checks the values `5` and `4`, you tell it that 5 is greater than 4 and should go after. But if it checks `4` and `5`, you tell it that they are equal. This is contradictory, and therefore the behaviour is undefined, resulting in the "random" sorting you see.

Try this:

```
return a == b ? 0 : (a > b ? 1 : -1);
```